# laravel - controller passing data to view (use return redirect to )

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

below is my route code

```
Route::any("rgMain/SystemManage/Account" , function()
{
$c1 = "rg.SystemManage.AccountManage.Account.Account_Factor";
$c2 = "rg.SystemManage.AccountManage.Account.Account_Result";

return View::make("rgMain",array(
        'rgFactor'   => $c1 ,
        'rgContent'  => $c2 

));
```

this is my controller code:

```
return Redirect::to('rgMain/SystemManage/Account')->with('message2', $output);
```

when do something done in webpage Account , submit param to controller , 
after vaild , controller would return Redirect::to route ,and carry message2 
back to Account , but i could'nt work

I am not sure this problem is or not about my structure
this my main struct , it could load different use webpage in here

```
<div>



<div>

</div>


<div>
     @include('rg.rgNotice')
</div>


<div>
     @include('rg.rgTitle')
</div>

<div>
    @include('rg.rgMenu', ['rg_Menu' => 'default'])
</div>


<div>
    @include($rgFactor, ['rg_Factor' => 'default'])
</div>



<div>
    @include($rgContent, ['rg_Result' => 'default'])
</div>
```

in rgMain.blade.php , try use  input.get('message2'); and $message2 , but
still couldn't work .

Answer (score 0):

When using `with()` with a `Redirect`, it actually flashes the data to the session so rather than trying to pull it from the input, try `Session::get('message2')`

Please note that this data would only be available during this request.

Answer (score 0):

Redirects using `with` flashes data to `session`
You are able to retrieve the data with:

```
{{ old('message2') }}
```